# How to properly organize this code?

Tags: python, oop

I'm creating  a basic rock-paper-scissors game to get familiar with python and tkinter. I wanted to create a gui and a logic class to separate the two. However, I can't seem to find a code layout that's both valid in python and makes sense to me.

I want the `Gui` class to only know about the widgets and update them.

```
class Gui:      
    def setup(self):
        root = Tk.Tk()
        root.geometry("370x170")
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        root.title("Rock, Paper, Scissors")
        root.iconbitmap("Play.ico")

        rock_button = Tk.Button(root, text="Rock", command=rock_clicked)
        rock_button.place(width=100, height=30, x=10, y=30)

        paper_button = Tk.Button(root, text="Paper", command=paper_clicked)
        paper_button.place(width=100, height=30, x=10, y=70)

        scissors_button = Tk.Button(root, text="Scissors", command=scissors_clicked)
        scissors_button.place(width=100, height=30, x=10, y=110)

        score_font = font.Font(family="Helvetica", size=20)

        own_score_lbl = Tk.Label(root, text="0", relief=Tk.RIDGE, font=score_font)
        own_score_lbl.place(width=50, height=110, x=120, y=30)

        ai_score_lbl = Tk.Label(root, text="0", relief=Tk.RIDGE, font=score_font)
        ai_score_lbl.place(width=50, height=110, x=200, y=30)

        ai_choice = Tk.Label(root, relief=Tk.RIDGE)
        ai_choice.place(width=100, height=110, x=260, y=30)

        root.mainloop()

gui = Gui()
gui.setup()
```

In other languages, I'm used to having a logic member variable in the gui class, and vice versa. That doesn't work here. The click handler functions can't be members of the logic class, becuase of the `self` argument. So I tried to declare them module-level, and call methods of the logic class from those, that didn't work out either.

Ideally, after a click event, I would expect a logic class method to be called, which then makes it's calculations, and calls an appropriate gui method back i.e. `set_label_text()`.

How can I accomplish this with an OO design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am definitely not an Tkinter expert, this is my first Tkinter app.

But here is my proposal how to use Python class inheritance to organize your solution.

The code runs

```
import Tkinter
import tkFont as font

class Gui(Tkinter.Tk):      
    def __init__(self, logic):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.logic = logic

        self.geometry("370x170")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        rock_button = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Rock", command=self.rock_clicked)
        rock_button.place(width=100, height=30, x=10, y=30)

        paper_button = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Paper", command=self.paper_clicked)
        paper_button.place(width=100, height=30, x=10, y=70)

        scissors_button = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Scissors", command=self.scissors_clicked)
        scissors_button.place(width=100, height=30, x=10, y=110)

        score_font = font.Font(family="Helvetica", size=20)

        own_score_lbl = Tkinter.Label(self, text="0", relief=Tkinter.RIDGE, font=score_font)
        own_score_lbl.place(width=50, height=110, x=120, y=30)

        ai_score_lbl = Tkinter.Label(self, text="0", relief=Tkinter.RIDGE, font=score_font)
        ai_score_lbl.place(width=50, height=110, x=200, y=30)

        ai_choice = Tkinter.Label(self, relief=Tkinter.RIDGE)
        ai_choice.place(width=100, height=110, x=260, y=30)

        self.render_title()

    def render_title(self):
        logic = self.logic
        templ = "Rock({logic.rock_counter}), Paper({logic.paper_counter}), Scissors({logic.scissors_counter})"
        title = templ.format(logic=logic)
        self.title(title)

    def rock_clicked(self):
        self.logic.play_rock()
        self.render_title()

    def paper_clicked(self):
        self.logic.play_paper()
        self.render_title()

    def scissors_clicked(self):
        self.logic.play_scissors()
        self.render_title()

class GameLogic():
    def __init__(self):
        self.rock_counter = 0
        self.paper_counter = 0
        self.scissors_counter = 0

    def play_rock(self):
        self.rock_counter += 1

    def play_paper(self):
        self.paper_counter += 1

    def play_scissors(self):
        self.scissors_counter += 1

logic = GameLogic()
game = Gui(logic)
game.mainloop()
```

## Gui Inheriting from `Tkinter.Tk`

- we get all the methods from Tk, incl. `mainloop`

## Using Gui `__init__` constructor

First, we ask our parent class to initialize, this is the Tkinter.Tk.**init**(self)

Then we refer to former `root` as `self`.

## Adding logic to Gui

`Logic` is implemented as independent class, it knows noting about frontend, it only expects calls to it's methods.

We instantiate `logic` in advance and pass it to Gui constructore.

There must be a contract, what methods and properties is Logic going to provide.

## Using Logic from Gui

When Gui finds out, there is some logic related event, it can call methods of `logic`.

After changes of the logic, it is often needed (withing Gui method) to rerender something.

## Start that up

This shall be the patter to follow:

1. instantiate logic
2. create gui, passing the logic in
3. let it run

translated to Python:

```
logic = GameLogic()
game = Gui(logic)
game.mainloop()
```

Comment: I get some ideas from your answer, but still, this way, the logic code would be defined inside a class called `Gui`. This is one of the things I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Innkeeper I will try to get it out by using Mixins

Comment: @Innkeeper I did not manage it by mixins (were running into neverending loop), but managed it via `logic` object being passed to Gui constructor. This will be probably easier to read then mixins.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed, thanks. Somehow I didn't think of passing the logic, I always thought about creating a logic instance there, which cannot be done before declaration. Thanks!